# How to reload a view every minute in iOS?

Tags: ios, view, uikit, nstimer

I have the following problem - I have a radio app. I am parsing the current song's title from a web HTML element and displaying it in a label. I am loading this element every minute in my function with an `NSTimer` to see if it has been changed. Here is my function:

```
-(void)parsing
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://live.radioeuphoria.bg:41232/played.html?sid=1"];
    NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *xPathQuery = @"//tr[2]/td[2]";
    TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData: webData];
    NSArray *array = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQuery];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        CLTickerView *ticker = [[CLTickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 798, 556, 50)]; // movable text
        for (TFHppleElement *element in array)
        {
            ticker.marqueeStr = [[element firstChild] content];
        }
    // ticker.marqueeStr = @"Current song's title";
        ticker.marqueeFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:42];
        [self.view addSubview:ticker];
        NSLog(@"bla bla");
    }
    else
    {
        CLTickerView *ticker = [[CLTickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(86, 346, 230, 30)]; // movable text
        for (TFHppleElement *element in array)
        {
            ticker.marqueeStr = [[element firstChild] content];
        }
        ticker.marqueeFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
        [self.view addSubview:ticker];
        NSLog(@"bla bla");
    }
}
```

In my `viewDidLoad` I am doing this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self parsing];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(parsing) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

In that way every single minute the label appears on the old one, instead of replacing it. How to replace the old view which I am displaying (`[self.view addSubview:ticker];`) with the new one?

Comment: what is your problem here?

Comment: The problem is that the labels are overlap each other. In five minutes I will have 5 labels, instead of one replacing the old one every minute.

Comment: is it solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once refer this one

```
     -(void)parsing
        {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://live.radioeuphoria.bg:41232/played.html?sid=1"];
            NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            NSString *xPathQuery = @"//tr[2]/td[2]";
            TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData: webData];
            NSArray *array = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQuery];
            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            {
                CLTickerView *ticker = [[CLTickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 798, 556, 50)]; 
    // here every time you are creating ticker that's why it overlaps remove this on here and add in viewDidload (define ticker globally). 

                for (TFHppleElement *element in array)
                {
                    ticker.marqueeStr = [[element firstChild] content];
                }
            // ticker.marqueeStr = @"Current song's title";
                ticker.marqueeFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:42];
                [self.view addSubview:ticker];
                NSLog(@"bla bla");
            }
            else
            {
                CLTickerView *ticker = [[CLTickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(86, 346, 230, 30)];
 // here every time you are creating ticker that's why it overlaps remove this on here and add in viewDidload (define ticker globally).
                for (TFHppleElement *element in array)
                {
                    ticker.marqueeStr = [[element firstChild] content];
                }
                ticker.marqueeFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
                [self.view addSubview:ticker];
                NSLog(@"bla bla");
            }
        }
```